# Giving user 2nd attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game there is a grid with words in to spell. The user is given a highlighted area in the grid and some clues like a picture and a sound of a word like "cat" for example.

The user then is supposed to click the corresponding letters on the side of the grid to achieve the correct answer.

If the user correctly spells the word, the word fades out to show a section of the image behind. The aim of the game is to spell all the words correctly and reveal the the whole image

If the user gets the spelling of a word wrong, there is a style applied to the word that makes it glow red, this should then fade after 2 seconds and he/she should be given another attempt to try to spell the word.

Currently when a word is spelt incorrectly the style appears to make the word glow red, but it does not go after 2 seconds and the user is not given another shot at the word.

I have used this line of code to get rid of the style's after 2 seconds...

```
$('.drop-box.spellword').removeClass('wordglow wordglow3 wordglow4', "2000");
```

For some reason it doesn't work

The script that adds the styles is here...

```
if (!$('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied)').length) {
            var wordIsCorrect = 0;
            $('.drop-box.spellword').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("data-letter") == $(this).find("div").attr("data-letter")) {
                    wordIsCorrect++;
                }
            });
            console.log(wordIsCorrect);
            console.log($('.drop-box.spellword').length);
            if ($('.drop-box.spellword').length == wordIsCorrect) {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass('wordglow2');
                $(right).val('Well Done!');
                $(right).show();
                audioS.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(wrong).hide();
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);

            } else {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass("wordglow4").css('color', 'transparent');
                $(wrong).val('Try Again');
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled');
                $(wrong).show();
                audioF.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(right).hide();
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', true);   

            }
```

To give the user another attempt I thought you may use something like this..

```
$('.drop-box.spellword').splice(0, $('.drop-box.spellword').length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use javascript's setTimeout function, for jQuery's removeClass doesn't accept an argument for timeouts.
Also, removeClass only removes one class at the time, so you have to chain them.

try replacing this:

```
$('.drop-box.spellword').removeClass('wordglow wordglow3 wordglow4', "2000");
```

for this:

```
setInterval(
   function(){
       $('.drop-box.spellword').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow3').removeClass('wordglow4');
   }, 2000
);
```

Comment: Seems to only get rid of "wordglow4" @André Alçada Padez

Comment: sorry, i was focusing on the other part of the problem, check my edit

Comment: Have a look at my fiddle because the other styles are applied in a different part of the code http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/3qaGK/26/ @André Alçada Padez

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) doesn't support passing a second parameter to be considered as a timer, but you can do this manually using setTimeout():

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.drop-box.spellword').removeClass('wordglow wordglow3 wordglow4');
}, 2000);
```

As for giving the user another attempt, why are you using `splice()`? Isn't each element with class drop-box.spellword a text input with individual strings? In that case you can use `$('.drop-box.spellword').val('')` to clear all inputs of that class.

**Edit:**

To remove the classes from the other children modify it to something like this:

$('.drop-box.spellword').removeClass('wordglow4');
$('.drop-box.spellword').children('.ui-widget-content').removeClass('wordglow')

The jsFiddle is really large so I'm not sure where wordglow3 gets applied, but the principle is the same, find the element and removeClass() from it, all in your timed function.

Comment: Seems to only get rid of "wordglow4" @xqwzts

Comment: sorry, i was focusing on the other part of the problem, check my edit

Comment: Sorry, which edit? could you send me a fiddle? @André Alçada Padez

Comment: sorry, i wished to comment on my answer, not here

Comment: @sMilbz "wordglow4" is the only class applied to ".drop-box.spellword", you have to get the other children and remove their classes manually.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the class after 2 seconds, use this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.drop-box.spellword').removeClass('wordglow wordglow3 wordglow4')
},2000)
```

`removeClass` doesn't accept any argument for a delay before removing a class.
I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `splice`, but one error I can see is that you forgot a `$` before `('.drop-box.spellword')` inside the `splice()` call.

Comment: Seems to only get rid of "wordglow4" @Abraham

Comment: It looks like the only class you're adding is `wordglow4`.

Comment: Oh sorry they are added further up the code, could you have a look? http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/3qaGK/26/ @Abraham

Comment: It looks like the `wordglow` class is being applied to the `div` inside the `td`, not the `td` itself.

Comment: How would I get rid of it at the same time I get rid of wordglow4? @Abraham

Comment: Just do something like this: `$('.drop-box.spellword').removeClass('wordglow4').children().removeClass('wordglow')`

Comment: Would it be something like this $(b.clone()).removeClass(
        b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow",); @Abraham